# How to implement PayU Objective C library in Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, payu

https://github.com/PayU/paytouch-ios I pasted SDK folder into my project and created Bridging-Header.h in which I have imported **#import "PUSDK.h"** and when I trying to do init in my viewController in viewDidLoad **let paymentService = PUPaymentService()** and app crashes without error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PUPaymentServiceDelegate{


func paymentServiceDidRequestPresenting(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
    self.navigationController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: {

    })
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let paymentService = PUPaymentService()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
extension ViewController: PUAuthorizationDataSource{
func refreshToken(completionHandler: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
    completionHandler("", nil)
}

func applicationCallbackScheme() -> String {
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Did you add an exception breakpoint in Xcode? That will hopefully tell you where the actual crash is happening.

Comment: You can write to their support team. They will check your code and let u know the issue.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps how to add the SDK to your project in their tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I have made break point and it crashes on init.

Comment: So what does the debugger tell you when it crashes with the breakpoint?

Comment: @Koen error: execution stopped with unexpected state.
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: breakpoint 4.1.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this. All I had to do was uncheck "Debug executable" in "edit scheme" There is some bug in library.